# Como fechar um JFrame usando eventos do teclado?

Tags: java, swing, eventos, teclado

Tenho um JFrame que eu quero que feche quando eu pressionar a tecla Esc...

Pois bem, eu fiz isso:

```
public Cadastro() {
    addKeyListener(this);
```

E depois isso:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
        dispose();
    }
}
```

Se vocês quiserem ver a classe inteira:

```
package Classes;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Cadastro extends javax.swing.JFrame implements KeyListener{

public Cadastro() {
    initComponents();
    setIcone();
    new Connect().Open();
    addKeyListener(this);
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Título = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    Editora = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Altor = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    Comentário = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Nota = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    BotaoEnviar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BotaoLimpar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    aviso = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Cadastro");
    setResizable(false);
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowClosed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Título");

    Título.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 0, 11)); // NOI18N

    Editora.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 0, 11)); // NOI18N

    jLabel2.setText("Editora");

    Altor.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 0, 11)); // NOI18N

    jLabel3.setText("Altor(a)");

    jLabel4.setText("Nota");

    Comentário.setColumns(20);
    Comentário.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
    Comentário.setLineWrap(true);
    Comentário.setRows(5);
    Comentário.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            ComentárioKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(Comentário);

    jLabel5.setText("Comentários");

    Nota.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "", "1", "2",              "3", "4", "5" }));

    BotaoEnviar.setText("Enviar");
    BotaoEnviar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BotaoEnviarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BotaoLimpar.setText("Limpar");
    BotaoLimpar.setToolTipText("Limpa os compos de texto.");
    BotaoLimpar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BotaoLimparActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    aviso.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 0, 11)); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(BotaoEnviar)
                    .addGap(72, 72, 72)
                    .addComponent(BotaoLimpar)
                    .addGap(78, 78, 78))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(Editora, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(Título, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 20, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(Altor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(Nota, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(29, 29, 29))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(aviso)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(Título, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(Altor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(Editora, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(Nota, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(BotaoLimpar)
                .addComponent(BotaoEnviar))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 34, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(aviso))
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void BotaoLimparActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    Título.setText(null);
    Editora.setText(null);
    Altor.setText(null);
    Comentário.setText(null);
    Nota.setSelectedIndex(0);
    aviso.setText(null);
}                                           

private void BotaoEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon(Cadastro.class.getResource("/Recursos/check.png"));

    String T = Título.getText();
    String A = Altor.getText();
    String E = Editora.getText();
    String N = "";
    String C = Comentário.getText();

    int select = Nota.getSelectedIndex();

    switch(select){
        case 0: N = "";
        break;
        case 1: N = "1";
        break;
        case 2: N = "2";
        break;
        case 3: N = "3";
        break;
        case 4: N = "4";
        break;
        case 5: N = "5";
        break;
    }

    String query = "insert into tablivros (`Título`, `Altor`, `Editora`, `Comentário`, `Nota`) values ('"+T+"', '"+A+"', '"+E+"', '"+C+"', '"+N+"')";

    new Connect().Execute(query);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Livro cadastrado com sucesso!", "Cadastro", 0, ico);
}                                           

private void formWindowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    new Connect().Close();
}                                 

private void ComentárioKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
    int c = Comentário.getText().length();

    if(c > 16777215){
        BotaoEnviar.setEnabled(false);
        aviso.setText("Faça um comentário menor.");
        aviso.setForeground(Color.red);
    } else{
        aviso.setText(null);
    }

}                                   

private void setIcone() {
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Entrada.class.getResource("/Recursos/icone.png")));
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
        dispose();
    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Cadastro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Cadastro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Cadastro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Cadastro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Pesquisa().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField Altor;
private javax.swing.JButton BotaoEnviar;
private javax.swing.JButton BotaoLimpar;
private javax.swing.JTextArea Comentário;
private javax.swing.JTextField Editora;
private javax.swing.JComboBox Nota;
private javax.swing.JTextField Título;
private javax.swing.JLabel aviso;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
// End of variables declaration                   

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

}
```

Só que desse jeito não está dando certo, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Chegou a debugar? O pressionamento da tecla foi realmente capturado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*`KeyListener`s*  adicionados em frames ou painéis não capturam as teclas se o foco estiver num campo ou outro componente dentro daquele formulário. Uma alternativa seria adicionar o listener recursivamente a todos os componentes.

Uma solução mais limpa é usar o `KeyboardFocusManager` para capturar globalmente as teclas pressionadas no seu programa.

Fiz um teste removendo os listeners e adicionando o seguindo código ao construtor da sua classe:

```
KeyboardFocusManager
    .getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
    .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                if(e.getID() == e.KEY_RELEASED 
                        && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
                    dispose();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Grato! Funcionou pra mim.

Answer (score 1):

Da forma que está fazendo (creio eu que) o evento nunca será disparado. Há um tempo precisei criar algo semelhante e precisei de uma `AbstractAction` pra definir o que deveria ocorrer quando a tecla <kbd>esc</kbd> fosse pressionada.

```
// Define que nada deve acontecer quando o usuário tentar fechar a janela.
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "FoiPressionadoOESC"
);     

getRootPane().getActionMap().put("FoiPressionadoOESC", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       fecharJanela();
    }
});

// Como foi definido para "nada" ocorrer quando tentar fechar a janela
// mesmo que o usuário clique no 'x' a janela nãos será fechada. Então
// método serve para a janela ter comportamento padrão. 
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
       fecharJanela();
    }
});
```

E então, quando o <kbd>esc</kbd> for pressionado ou o usuário clicar no 'x' para fechar a janela, o método `fecharJanela` será chamado. Nele você pode definir o que deve ser feito quando a janela for fechada, por exemplo:

```
private void fecharJanela(){
  this.dispose();
}
```

#### código de teste:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MeuFrame extends JFrame {

    public MeuFrame(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "EscPressed"
        );

        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("EscPressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fecharJanela();
            }
        });
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
                fecharJanela();
            }
        });
    }

    private void fecharJanela(){
        this.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MeuFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```