# atribuir uma funçao a uma tecla no teclado

Tags: java, teclado, funções

Estou criando um aplicativo para um leilão de gado onde possui lote, sexo do animal, se é a vista ou a prazo e o campo de valor do lote onde vai aumentando enquato o leiloeiro fala o lance.

Ficar digitando o valor manualmente perde muito tempo então eu quero atribuir a tecla "." para aumentar mais 5 reais, a tecla "+" para aumentar 10 reais, a tecla "-" para aumentar 20 reais e a tecla "*" para aumentar 50 reais.

Como eu atribuo esta função para as teclas.

Segue abaixo o código da tela.

Comment: Onde está o código? [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/55946/edit) sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Há duas formas básicas de fazer isso.

## `KeyListener` nos componentes

A primeira é adicionar um `KeyListener` aos seus componentes para capturar os eventos de teclado, verificar as teclas pressionadas e tomar a ação necessária.

Entretanto, esse listener só funciona se os componentes tem o foco, então precisa ser adicionado em cada componente que pode ter o foco quando pressionado.

Veja como implementar um [`KeyListener` no tutorial oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

## Listener global

Se quiser um listener global no seu programa, pode usar a classe `KeyboardFocusManager`.

Veja o [exemplo que publiquei em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55960/227).