# Como usar click do mouse e ENTER do teclado?

Tags: java, swing

Como incluir na minha classe, um evento que me dê a possibilidade de clicar no `JButton` e ele mostrar um `JOptionPane`? E, da mesma forma, no mesmo `JButton`, eu pressionar o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> e ele me mostrar o mesmo `JOptionPane`?

Answer (score 4):

Os eventos de cliques podem ser capturados por meio de um [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html). O de pressionar uma determinada tecla pode ser obtido com [`KeyEventDispatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyEventDispatcher.html) junto ao [`KeyboardFocusManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html).

[Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55960/4808) do utluiz explica porque é melhor utilizar `KeyboardFocusManager` ao invés de adicionar um [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) para o seu botão. Embora ambos servem para capturar eventos do teclado, o `KeyListener` não funciona se o foco estiver em um outro componente.

Um exemplo simples que exibe um `JOptionPane` quando a tecla <kbd>**ENTER**</kbd> for pressionada ou quando houver o evento de *click* no `JButton`:

```
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MeuJFrame extends JFrame {

    public MeuJFrame() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Mostrar JOptionPane");
        getContentPane().add(btn);

        // Quando clicado
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mostrarJOptionPane();
            }
        });

        // Quando uma tecla for pressionada (Nesse exemplo escolhi a tecla 'B').
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
            .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
                @Override
                public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
                    if(event.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED 
                       && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                           mostrarJOptionPane();
                           return true;
                     }
                     return false;
                }
        }); 
    }

    private void mostrarJOptionPane(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MeuJFrame().setVisible(true);
    }  
}
```

Como o `KeyboardFocusManager` captura todos os eventos, é preciso fazer uma restrição para fazer algo somente quando uma tecla for pressionada e solta ([`KeyEvent#KEY_RELEASED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#KEY_RELEASED)), por isso esse trecho:

```
if(event.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED ...
```

Do contrário, será disparada uma ação (no caso, mostrar o `JOptionPane`) a cada evento capturado: `KeyEvent#KEY_RELEASED`, [`KeyEvent#KEY_PRESSED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#KEY_PRESSED) e [`KeyEvent#KEY_TYPED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#KEY_TYPED).

Comment: Posso aplicar este mesmo comportamento à um JFRAME, ao invés de apenas a um botão?

Comment: @pmargreff qual comportamento?

Comment: Usar a keyboardFocusManager, preciso implementar mas por algum motivos ainda não encontrado nenhuma das respostas me ajudou.

Comment: Não sei, não entendi o que quer fazer, talvez seja melhor criar uma pergunta para isso.

Answer (score 0):

Peguei o click do 'Enter' em uma textfield no javafx assim:

```
   private void clikBusc(KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            System.out.println("deu certo");
        }
    }
```

Assim, sempre que eu clico no enter dentro da textField, vai entrar no if, e executar o que for posto dentro!

Comment: Por favor leia a outra resposta, que diz justamente que utilizar KeyEvent para o caso desta pergunta é uma pratica ruim. E uma pequena dica: Só porque funciona, não significa que esteja correto.