# Diferença entre métodos para fechar JFrame e JDialog após evento do teclado

Tags: java, swing, eventos, teclado

Estou precisando implementar em uma aplicação desktop construída usando `swing`, uma forma para que o `JFrame` principal feche a aplicação quando o usuário clicar em <kbd>ESC</kbd>, e as `JDialogs` filhas deste `JFrame`, fechem apenas a si mesmas ao apertar <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Pesquisando aqui mesmo no sopt, encontrei [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55939/como-fechar-um-jframe-usando-eventos-do-teclado) a respeito, mas algumas dúvidas relativas ao código das duas respostas postadas respectivamente pelo [@utluiz♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55960/28595) e pelo [@renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55959/28595), onde o primeiro usa um recurso que não sobrescreve o método `windowClosing` e o segundo já sobrescreve este método, delegando o fechamento a um método personalizado.

Existe diferença entre usar o `AbstractAction` e o `KeyboardFocusManager` para este fim? Ambos podem afetar de alguma maneira outros listeners usados na aplicação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após efetuar uns testes com as duas formas sugeridas nas respostas citadas na pergunta, a algumas conclusões a respeito dos dois modos:

### Utilizando KeyboardFocusManager

Utilizando a classe [`KeyboardFocusManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html), como foi sugerido pelo @utluiz♦, o evento fica "ouvindo" todas as ações de teclado, em qualquer componente do Frame e também de outras janelas as quais este Frame serve de referência. No caso da pergunta, as JDialogs também invocam o evento, caso a tecla <kbd>ESC</kbd> seja apertada, fechando a aplicação mesmo o método tendo sido implementado apenas no Frame principal "pai", e este estando fora de foco por causa do `JDialog`.

Este comportamento é interessante caso queira que a tecla seja um "atalho coringa" na aplicação, mas para o caso da pergunta em específico, acaba por trazer um comportamento não desejado, pois se você apertar esta tecla para sair da edição de um componente como uma célula de um `JTable`, a aplicação também é fechada imediatamente.

---

### Utilizando AbstractAction

Já a forma sugerida na resposta do @renan, utilizando [`AbstractAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html), o evento não interfere dentro de uma célula da `JTable`, como o exemplo citado anteriormente, e não fica "escutando" o teclado em outras janelas filhas, provavelmente pelo fato de ser adicionado apenas como evento do painel root daquele Frame.

Apesar de ter uma complexidade um pouco maior para adicionar este tipo de evento as janelas em comparação com o método anterior(para funcionar em todas as janelas, deve se adicionado em cada uma separadamente), para o meu caso esta opção acabou atendendo pelo fato de não afetar edições nas células da `JTable` da aplicação e também pela possibilidade de fazer com que a tecla apertada apenas feche a janela em foco no momento, e não finalizar a aplicação.