# Como criar atalho pra abrir um JMenu?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

Fala galera, alguém sabe como se faz para criar um método de atalhos do teclado pra abrir um **JMenu**. Por exemplo, clicar em F1 ou CTRL + "alguma coisa" e abrir uma tela.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55939/como-fechar-um-jframe-usando-eventos-do-teclado/55960#55960

Comment: Diegofm, deu certinho isso ai. Coloca como resposta pra poder votar nela!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fechar um JFrame usando eventos do teclado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55939/como-fechar-um-jframe-usando-eventos-do-teclado)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a classe [`KeyboardFocusManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html) para capturar os eventos do teclado e verificar qual foi o [evento](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) que o acionou:

```
KeyboardFocusManager
        .getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
        .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
          @Override
          public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            if (e.getID() == e.KEY_RELEASED && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F1) {
              jMenu1.setPopupMenuVisible(true);
              jMenu1.setArmed(true);
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          }
        });
```

No exemplo acima o menu `jMenu1` ao apertar a tecla <kbd>F1</kbd>.

> [`KeyboardFocusManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html)
>
> The KeyboardFocusManager is responsible for managing the active and focused Windows, and the current focus owner. The focus owner is defined as the Component in an application that will typically receive all [`KeyEvents`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) generated by the user.

Em tradução livre:

> O KeyboardFocusManager é responsável por gerenciar a janela ativa e focada, e o detentor do foco. O detentor do foco é definido como o componente na aplicação que irá tipicamente receber todos os [`KeyEvents`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) gerados pelo usuário.

---

> [`KeyEvents`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)
>
> An event which indicates that a keystroke occurred in a component.

Em tradução livre:

> Um evento que indica qual a tecla que foi pressionada em um componente.

Referência: [**Como fechar um JFrame usando eventos do teclado?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55939/como-fechar-um-jframe-usando-eventos-do-teclado/55960#55960)

Comment: e se eu quiser usar CTRL + alguma letra? posso fazer um KeyEvent.VK_F1+ alguma coisa ? Digo isso pois isso aumentaria minhas opções de atalhos.

Comment: Sim, se não me engano é só você adicionar isso ao if: (e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)

Comment: Opa, deu certinho ! Teria como me explicar a função dessa linha ? pra mim entender bem o que ela esta fazendo.                                             if (e.getID() == e.KEY_RELEASED && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A && (e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)

Comment: Sim. A primeira parte é pra verificar o tipo do event, que no caso é o Key Released (ou seja, quando você soltar a tecla). A segunda parte verifica se a tecla pressionada é que você deseja, no caso "A". A terceira parte verifica se existe alguma tecla de função (Como por exemplo Shift, CTRL ou Alt) pressionada em conjunto.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Veja este exemplo, acho que vai te servir:

```
JMenu actionMenu = new JMenu("Actions");
actionMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

Onde o menu será acessado com as teclas <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

*Att*.

Comment: Não deu certo não Andrey França.